# ng-click on image to check a radiobox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

### **Question**

**How do I make the appropriate drop down visible when I click on the image or the checkbox.**
*In the end the radiobox will be hidden.*

Currently the radio button does get checked but it does make the options appear properly?  I think it's a scoping issue.

### [live code](http://jsfiddle.net/djwruftr/2/)

I have a collection of colors and sizes:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {
 $scope.productData = {
  "colors_and_sizes": {
    "data": {
      "Black": {
        "swatch_image": 'http://lorempixel.com/50/50',
        "sizes": "X Small, Small, Medium, Large, Xlarge, XX Large"
      },
      "Blue": {
        "swatch_image": 'http://lorempixel.com/50/50',
        "sizes": "X Small, Small, Medium, Large, Xlarge, XX Large"
      }
    }
  }
};

});
```

HTML:  here is my form

```
<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="color-pick" ng-repeat="(key, val) in productData.colors_and_sizes.data">
        <input type="radio" ng-checked="selected" name="colors" ng-model="$parent.myColor" ng-value="key" />
        <img ng-click="selected = true" ng-src="{{val.swatch_image}}" alt="">{{key}} 
        <div class="size-pick" ng-show="$parent.myColor==key">
            <select ng-model="$parent.mySize" ng-options="size for size in val.sizes.split(',')"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    myColor: {{myColor}}<br/>
    mySize: {{mySize}}
</form>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the radio button does get checked but it DOESN'T make the options appear properly. How would you like them to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you defined `$parent.myColor` in order to save a value of the radio button. So if you want to be able to show the drop down based on the selected image, you can use `ng-click` on the img tag, as you already did, and assign the new value to it.

```
<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="color-pick" ng-repeat="(key, val) in productData.colors_and_sizes.data">
        <input type="radio" name="colors" ng-model="$parent.myColor" ng-value="key" />
        <img ng-click="$parent.myColor = key" ng-src="{{val.swatch_image}}" alt="">{{key}} 
        <div class="size-pick" ng-show="$parent.myColor==key">
            <select ng-model="$parent.mySize" ng-options="size for size in val.sizes.split(',')"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    myColor: {{myColor}}<br/>
    mySize: {{mySize}}
</form>
```

[Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/djwruftr/3/).